# Binary files read & write

Tags: c, project, binaryfiles

So I have a problem with binary file.(Yea i'm a beginner, but I know some things.)

Why does my binary file not "remember" what I wrote last time I run my program?

It's like it just deletes everything or just can't read what's inside file, so every time I run my program I need to write all parameteres again.

Header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

typedef struct user {
    char name[30];
    char last_name[30];
    int id_number;
    int phone;
} USER;

void reading(FILE*, int, USER*);
void writeing(FILE*, int, USER*);


#endif
```

This is inside main(Source.c)

```
int main() {

    int n = 0, user_number = 0;

    USER *user = NULL;
    user = (USER*)calloc(100, sizeof(USER));
    FILE *dat = NULL;

    while (n != 4) {
        printf("Press 1 for creating binary file! \n");
        printf("Press 2 for reading! \n");
        printf("Press 3 to enter new user! \n");
        printf("Press 4 to exit!\n\n");
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("\n");

        switch (n)
        {
        case 1:
            dat = fopen("User.bin", "wb");
            printf("File created.\n");
            fclose(dat);
            break;

        case 2:
            dat = fopen("User.bin", "rb");
            reading(dat, user_number, user);
            printf("\n");
            fclose(dat);
            break;

        case 3:
            user_number++;
            printf("Insert details of %d user: \n", user_number);
            dat = fopen("User.bin", "ab");
            writeing(dat, user_number, user);
            printf("\n");
            fclose(dat);
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("Program closed!\n");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    free(user);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This is inside function, also functions are organized in different file(Functions.c).

```
void writeing(FILE* dat, int user_number, USER* user) {

    int i = user_number- 1;

    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", (user + i)->name);

    printf("Last name: ");
    scanf("%s", (user + i)->last_name);

    printf("ID number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(user + i)->id_number);

    printf("Phone: ");
    scanf("%d", &(user + i)->phone);
    fwrite(user, sizeof(*user), 1, dat);
}


void reading(FILE* dat, int user_number, USER* user)
{
    fread(user, sizeof(USER), user_number, dat);
    for (int i = 0; i < user_number; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nID number: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n", (user + i)->name, (user + i)->last_name, (user + i)->id_number, (user + i)->phone);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any code about writing something into a file, your function `writeing` should used `dat` if you want to have something stored

Comment: I tried this  
`fwrite(user, sizeof(USER), sizeof(user) / sizeof(USER), dat);`
Not working.

Comment: when calling the C library functions: `scanf()` `fopen()`  `fwrite()` `fread()`  always check the returned value (not any parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  when not successful, output to `stderr` a message indicating the error. (and if available) use `perror()` so the system text about the error is also output to `stderr`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `fprintf( stderr, "...\n", ... );` to output the error message to `stderr`, because the `scanf()` family does not update `errno` when a input fails.  2) when using the input/format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always use a MAX FIELD LENGTH modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those items always append a NUL byte to the input.  avoiding undefined behavior from a buffer overflow

Comment: Please post the struct definition AND the typedef for `USER`

Comment: where is the code that you are expecting to write to the file?  Since it is a 'binary' file, I would expect you to use `fwrite()`.  And be sure to check the returned value to assure the write was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't write anything to the file, at least not in the snippet of code you provided. Probably what you want to do is:

```
// my guess what USER is, because you didn't provide.....
typedef struct USER_s {
char name[200];
char last_name[200];
int id_number;
int phone;
} USER;

void writeing(FILE* dat, int user_number, USER* user) {

    int i = user_number- 1;

    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", (user + i)->name);

    printf("Last name: ");
    scanf("%s", (user + i)->last_name);

    printf("ID number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(user + i)->id_number);

    printf("Phone: ");
    scanf("%d", &(user + i)->phone);

    // write 1 time sizeof(USER) length data pointed to by 'user' variable to dat file
    size_t ret = fwrite(&user[i], sizeof(*user), 1, dat);
    // assertion for safety
    assert(ret == sizeof(*user));
}

void ispis(FILE* dat, int user_number, USER* user)
{
    // read from dat file user_number times sizeof(USER) length data and save to user array
    // user pointer can handle sizeof(USER)*user_number bytes
    size_t ret = fread(user, sizeof(USER), user_number, dat);
    // assertion for safety
    assert(ret == sizeof(USER)*user_number);

    for (int i = 0; i < user_number; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nID number: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n", (user + i)->name, (user + i)->last_name, (user + i)->id_number, (user + i)->phone);
    }
}
```

Btw. You might interest yourself, that `(user + i)->name` is the same as `user[i].name`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that wasn't quite what I needed. It's my fault I didn't put all the code. I edited the code to show full main function. So if you can looked through it again it would mean the world to me, I understand if you have something more important to do.

Comment: You don't anywhere call `fwrite()` inside your `writeing()` to write anything to a the file and your call to `fread()` inside `ispis()` is malformed (`sizeof(user) / sizeof(USER)` will be always equal to 0 or 1, depends on architecture). When `n==3` you just open a file, scan user for input and close the file. You need to write smth to a file to save it there... My guess was, the function `writeing` should save the inputted data into the file and the function `ispis` should print out all saved data from the file to stdout.

Comment: Function `ispis()` is actually function `reading()`, that was my bad in edit. When I run the program with your lines of code, it still doesn't read what I wrote into the file some last time... When I choose to input 2 or more new users, it only reads the details of the first user [link](https://ibb.co/gttD8n).

Comment: There was a small typo i left in `fwrite()` call... Edited the answer, should work now...